# JSON returns an error when I'm using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm trying get json from this page

http://www.designerbh.com/js.php

but it returns an error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.designerbh.com/js.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Can someone help me?

```
function AJAX_JSON_Req( url )
{
 var AJAX_req = new XMLHttpRequest();
 AJAX_req.open( "GET", url, true );
 AJAX_req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

AJAX_req.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if( AJAX_req.readyState == 4 && AJAX_req.status == 200 )
      {
        var response = JSON.parse( AJAX_req.responseText );
        document.write( response.name );
       }
}
AJAX_req.send();
}
 AJAX_JSON_Req( 'http://www.designerbh.com/js.php' );
```

Comment: You cannot fetch content from random websites via ajax if they don't explicitly allow it.

Comment: how could i fix it ? do you  know ?

Comment: Guess what: if you type "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in Google, the first page is full of results that explain the issue in detail.

Comment: It's an intrinsic browser security feature. You can't "fix" it by any means other than creating a server-side proxy service to fetch the content for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will receive such warning if your browser supports Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, but the responding server doesn't allow your domain. Since you are trying to parse JSON, a workaround would be to use Ajax to load the content instead of `XMLHttpRequest`.

**Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- Loads jQuery 1.11.0 -->
</head>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://www.designerbh.com/js.php', //This is the URL we will be calling to gather the data from
        type: 'GET', //This is the type of our request
        dataType: "json", //switch to JSONP for JSONP
        success : callback, //Call callback() function when the request is complete to process the gathered data
        data: {
        //GET parameters should be specified here
        //Example
        //parameter1: "value1",
        //parameter2: "value2"
        }
    })
}
function callback(data) {
    //Since that http://www.designerbh.com/js.php gives out {"text":"omrele"}, we can access the text variable by calling data.text
    alert(data.text); //omrele
}
getData(); //call the getData() function to start sending the GET request
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked fines to me thanks you so much i tryed many script i setted the allow in header php and used this code tank you  so much

Answer (score 0):

In your case you're using a cross site ajax so you can use jsonp for such mission

You can use jquery for that

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://.....',
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(response){

}
})
```